# Is that true that taking pills causes stomach discomfort or pain?

Tags: dogs, behavior

A few days ago my dog started taking one antibiotics pill a day for a mild otitis. Then he started to cry a lot at night, always next to the house frontgate, as if he had a desperate need for walk. And he never seems to have it enough, as he keeps constantly crying for more all night along. He has even destructed a net we had attached to the frontgate. Also, during walks, he obsessively sniffs the ground, and doesn't want to go back home.

We don't know for sure, but gases medicine seems to have helped. We would like to be sure. Thanks.

Comment: If he neutered? He might just be amourous... our dog sometimes get hyper when there's a female dog in heat

Comment: @Journeyman Geek He is not neutered, however, when we go out to walk, he doesn't seek a specific direction, therefore I was not inclined to that hypothesis. It is very hot around here (it is Summer, in the tropics), and the environment is new to him (before, he used to stay in an apartment, now it is a house next to an avenue, in a crowded neighborhood), is that possible that the scents from other dogs' fluids on the streets are stronger due to the temperature and driving him crazy?

Comment: Its always hot where I live but I have found that these periods of hyperness lasts 2 or 3 weeks. The new environment might contribute as well

Comment: Welcome to Pets SE. :) Did anything change prior to this? When was the move from apartment to home? Is he in a crate at night?

Comment: @elbrant Well, there are many recent changes, but none on the last week, they happened few weeks ago. We got a baby 3 months ago. The change to the new house happened little before Christmas. He has since lived with more people, with some restrictions on areas of the house he cannot go, walking less than before, and this house is a lot hotter than the previous apartment. All this happened, but he looked alright till last week. And the strangest thing, he spends the day normally, he only starts to cry a lot at night.

Comment: Now my wife thinks it could be the meat she was feeding him recently. We never came to a conclusion, but he may be allergic. She decided to suspend the meat and observe what happens before getting back again to the vet. We are going to see the vet next week anyway, to check his ear after the treatment.

Comment: It could be related to something the dog ate, I was thinking a blanket over his crate might help him settle in and dampen the household noise so he can sleep.

Comment: A completely different idea: are there any electronic devices that are only turned on during the night? Like a baby monitor or an animal repeller in a car? Maybe something makes extremely high pitched noises that you cannot hear but affect your dog.

Comment: Since there is no answere yet, you should edit your question in a way that it reflects your latest insights. Please don't add another "chapter" to the question, but write it in a way as if you started from scratch and had all the information from the very beginning. Of special interest is the order of events: did the crying start after taking pills? Did it get better after taking the gases medicine? How many antibiotic treatments had the dog recently?

Comment: For clarification is he taking the medications orally? Typically ear infections are treated topically (with ear drops) unless very severe.

Comment: Yes, he is taking pills orally, as he had very clean ears and no local pain or any other severe symptoms aside from shaking his head or scratching his ear, but an opaque tympanus.